# Zurmo Cron Job Configuration

Tags: zurmocrm

Is there any good CRON configuration for Zurmo. The documentation seems less and forum are not much active. Zurmo was hosted in Google Compute VM using Bitnami. So it was installed in

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*/5 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user Monitor &> /dev/null
30 4 * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user CurrencyRatesUpdate &> /dev/null
30 2 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ImportCleanup &> /dev/null
*/30 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user AddressGeocodeUpdate &> /dev/null
0 */1 * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user AutoresponderQueueMessagesInOutbox &> /dev/null
0 */1 * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user CampaignGenerateDueCampaignItems &> /dev/null
0 */1 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user CampaignMarkCompleted &> /dev/null
0 */1 * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user CampaignQueueMessagesInOutbox &> /dev/null
0 22 * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ClearSentNotificationsEmail &> /dev/null
*/5 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user EmailArchiving &> /dev/null
*/5 * * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user EmailBounce &> /dev/null
*/1 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ProcessOutboundEmail &> /dev/null
0 22 * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user TestOutboundEmail &> /dev/null
5 18 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user DraftEmailTemplateCleanup &> /dev/null
5 18 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ExportCleanup &> /dev/null
5 18 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user CheckZurmoUpdates &> /dev/null
0 * */1 * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user JobLogCleanup &> /dev/null
0 */1 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user UpdateModelsLatestActivityDateTimeByMeeting &> /dev/null
*/15 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ByTimeWorkflowInQueue &> /dev/null
*/15 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user WorkflowMessageInQueue &> /dev/null
0 22  * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user WorkflowValidityCheck &> /dev/null
*/10 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ReadPermissionSubscriptionUpdate &> /dev/null
5 18 * * 6 cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user ShortUrlCleanup &> /dev/null
*/5 * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/zurmo/htdocs/app/protected/commands && ./zurmoc jobManager  user SendGridEmailEvents &> /dev/null
```